# Передача данных работающему приложению через командную строку.

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-basic, c++

Платформа Windows.

Приложение работает в качестве демона, т.е. постоянно запущено. необходимо передать данные в это приложение через командную строку. Что бы новый экземпляр приложения обнаружив запущенную копию передал в неё полученные через командную строку параметры. Как реализовать эту передачу. Желательно обойтись без сокетов.

Comment: Разными способами. От демона требуется, чтобы он мог получать сообщения. Используется вспомогательная программа (в принципе это может быть и исполняемый файл демона), которая запускается с нужными параметрами, передаёт их демону и завершается.

Comment: сначала определи как именно будешь передавать данные?
если из совсем другого приложения - сразу используй каналы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При запуске приложения с командной строки создается новый процесс, поэтому непосредственно передать эти параметры уже работающему приложению нельзя.

Обычно в таких случаях в приложение встраивают дополнительную логику. При запуске приложение проверяет, есть ли уже запущенный экземпляр и, если есть, то передает ему параметры командной строки, после чего завершает работу. Способы передачи данных от процесса к процессу могут быть самые разные - `WM_COPYDATA, DCOM, IPC` и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно три варианта:

1. Приложение имеет окно (хотя бы невидимое), и обработчик сообщений Windows перехватывает сообщение с определённым кодом, чтобы его обработать.
2. Приложение является WCF-сервисом.
3. Приложение является сервером именованных каналов.